# LINQ greater/less than not working in query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

`var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.Cost == 10M);` works perfectly fine and returns the correct list of results.
`var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.Cost > 10M);` throws an exception:

> `The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>.Where(p => p.Cost > (Nullable<decimal>)10)' could not be translated.`

Obviously the script being generated by C# can't be executed in SQL but why not? That is a valid SQL query

```
public class Product
    {
        public int ProductID {get;set;}
        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public string ProductName {get;set;}
        [Column("UnitPrice", TypeName="money")]
        public decimal? Cost {get;set;}
    }

    public class Northwind: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Category> Categories {get;set;}
        public DbSet<Product> Products {get;set;}
    }
```

EFCore 3.1.2,
.NET Core 3.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like `p.Cost` is a `decimal?`. In that case you can use the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).

```
var query = db.Products.Where(p => (p.Cost ?? 0) > 10M);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because Cost is a nullable decimale, i.e decimal?

Equals does not throw an error because it can check if null == 10M, however, to do a greater than it would have to go p.Cost.Value behind the scenes, but it does not know how to do that.

So two choices
Chane p.Cost to a 'decimal' rather than a nullable type OR
Assuming p.Cost is never null which is probably the case simply change the linq to

`p => p.Cost.Value > 10M`

Comment: So both you and Arthur have a good point that it's a nullable decimal type, but I've tried your suggestions and I still get that error. `var query = db.Products.Sum(p => p.Cost)` also doesn't work so am I missing something?

Comment: That's because `p => p.Cost` picks out the `Cost` property with is not strictly numeric, it's a nullable numeric.  Have you tried changing it to `p => p.Cost.Value` as @michaelCeber suggested?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @Bugbeeb As per my answer, have you tried `var query = db.Products.Sum(p => p.Cost ?? 0)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = db.Products.Where(p => p.Cost.HasValue && p.Cost.Value > 10M);
```

A readable form of this query can be written as above.