# C# Linq no working with "Greater than" operators

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Every time I try to run the following sentence in my function:

```cs
var comission = await _context.Comissions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => 
  c.CountryReceiverId == receiverCountryId && 
  c.CountrySenderId == senderCountryId);

var comissionRange = await _context.ComissionRanges
  .Where(c => c.MinAmount <= amount && c.MaxAmount >= amount)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ComissionId == comission.Id);
```

it gives me the following error:

> The LINQ expression `'DbSet<ComissionRange> .Where(c => c.MinAmount <= __amount_0 && c.MaxAmount >= __amount_0)'` could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

The error happens at the `comissionRange` query specifically, and I noticed the following, like if the problem it is with the `>=` or `<=` operator, for example if I modify such query like this:

```cs
var comissionRange = await _context.ComissionRanges
  .Where(c => c.MinAmount == 501 && c.MaxAmount == 1000)
  .FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ComissionId == comission.Id);
```

it works perfectly! It's like if the problem it's because I am using the `>=` and `<=` operators, what will be the right way to rewrite this query and make it work?

Comment: What are the types of `c.MinAmount`, `c.MaxAmount`, and `amount`? It should work the way you have it, but if they are different types you may need to convert them first.

Comment: What is the type of MinAmount and MaxAmount? Is it nullable? This may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60572586/120955

Comment: I'm sorry, they're all are "decimal", and they aren't nullable, but according to the values I have in the database and the input value I am trying, it should return a value.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you see the same behavior if the conditions in the `Where` condition get moved into the `FirstOrDefaultAsync` call, or vice versa?

Comment: The operator >= and <= seems ok. Please check your data type and DbSet configuration. Database type and C# type may be translated unmatch so you need to ensure using correct Data Type.

Comment: Define amount as an int and try again.

Comment: @KevinToruño does the query at the bottom works if you use >= and <= with those constant values?

Comment: Not that this addresses your question, but you might want to make the first query .First(...) as it's required for the second query.

Comment: Have you tried to cast it with toList() ? Else try to evaluate etc only "MinAmount" >=501 then try "MinAmount" >= amount  to locate the exact position of the error.

Comment: Where is `amount` declared?